# git is not respecting gitignore instruction to ignore .env files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a project. In the root directory are these 4 files:

> .env .env.example .env.local .env.staging

I have a .gitignore file, and I'm listing these 4 files in the .gitignore, one after another, like this

```
.env
.env.example
.env.local
.env.staging
```

My git repository does not contain .env or .env.example, but it DOES contain .env.local and .env.staging.
I've tried everything I can think of, but it keeps syncing these 2 files with git.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 497, accepted):

### Use [git rm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm):

If you have already added the files to be tracked, you need to remove them from tracking:

```
git rm env.local --cached
git rm env.staging --cached
git commit -m "Stopped tracking env.local, and env.staging"
```

Now you should be able to clone your branch without those files being tracked.

**Note:** Keep in mind that the contents of those files are in your history, and if they did contain sensitive data, then you need to [completely remove](http://www.ducea.com/2012/02/07/howto-completely-remove-a-file-from-git-history/) that from history before putting it out there.

Comment: What is the purpose of adding --cached ?

Comment: It should be `git rm .env.local --cached`, etc

Answer (score 233):

Simply Run This Command.

```
git rm .env --cached
git commit -m "Stopped tracking .env File"
```

In laravel there are .env file include for connecting database. So for that you must remove .env file from cached.

Answer (score 28):

You can remove that file from cached.

try below  command

```
git rm .env --cached
git commit -m "Any message"
```

Answer (score 16):

It is because your `.env` file has been pushed to git.

You should first delete that from git and push your changes.

```
rm -f .env
git add .
git commit -m "remove .env file from git"
git push
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to put the `.env` file in it's own folder, then add that folder to the `.gitignore` file.
example:

- create a folder called "vars"
- move your `.env` file into that folder
- add the `vars` folder in `.gitignore`

```
*inside .gitignore*

/node_modules
/vars
```

-Make sure you add the path to `dotenv.config()` in your main file where you use the `enviroment variables`

```
dotenv.config({path: "./vars/.env"}
```

Then you can continue to reference you environment variables the same way as before

Answer (score 3):

it's simple by updating the .gitignore:

```
*.env
*.env.example
*.env.local
*.env.staging
```

Comment: Hi , for OP , the problem is the files are committed into his git main/master repo, hence even listing or using wildcards in .gitignore will not work. All the answers related to removing the files first from git needs to be done first before listing the files in .gitignore

But after removing the files from git, devs could use your technique to use a wildcard so that all files with *.env convention get ignored.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use clear cache command, there's much simpler solution also doable in GUI.

If you are absolutely sure, your `.gitignore` rule is correct:

1. stage the file that is not being ignored (STAGE ONLY DON'T COMMIT)
2. unstage the file
3. The file should not appear in changes anymore

Answer (score 0):

If you think that in spite of adding filename gitignore is not working as expected, then  make sure that you remove that from from git first.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because the file was staged. I unstaged the .env file and it was ignored properly.